# DateTime stamp in output .zip file

Tags: c#, file, output, datestamp

I have a String Path to output a .ZIP file String `path = @"C:\TEMP\test.zip";` and I am looking to five the file name a date stamp. Example, test_TodayDate.ZIP.
There's a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.Today`) and `string.Format`. People are also more willing to help if you show what you've already tried.

Comment: `DateTime.Today.ToString(format)`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi thanks for the anwers. What I tried to to its to string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"); and then to output like this String path = @"C:\TEMP\test.zip" + timestamp; but its give me a file without format and what I am expecting its the zip file in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
string filePath = @"C:\TEMP\test.zip";
string finalPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath) 
                                  + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") 
                                  + Path.GetExtension(filePath));
```

- First Get File name without extension and add your Time Stamp, Then concatenate file extension,
- Then get Current directory for the file path
- Use Path.Combine to combine directory and new file name

Comment: Hi, I tried the follow but I am just getting the name of the file without the date. I did the follow String path = @"C:\TEMP\tests.zip";
                String finalPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
                                   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
                                  + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
                                  + Path.GetExtension(path));

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia, this should work fine, are you sure you are not checking `path`, your new path should be in `finalPath`

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, you were right. I was writing from the wrong filepath. I changed the follow System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, MyBinFiles); and it worked. Thanks you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own variable, like this,

```
// gets the file name without extension
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path); 
// create the new file name
var newFileName = fileName + "_" + DateTime.Now + ".zip";
```

Now save the new file generated, and name this file as the `newFileName` it will have the DateTime in the name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I tried the follow but the output has no data stamp extension String path = @"C:\TEMP\test.zip";

                var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                // create the new file name
                var newFileName = fileName + "_" + DateTime.Now + ".zip";